# Data are not showing in my tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I placed one table view inside my view controller and set the delegate and all. And the i use on `tableview` subclass of `UITableview cell`. And i did all coding part.Here is my code:

Tbaleview.h:

```
@interface TableView : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab2;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lab3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *checkBtn;
```

Tableview.m:

```
@implementation TableView
@synthesize lab1 = _lab1;
@synthesize lab2 = _lab2;
@synthesize lab3 = _lab3;
@synthesize checkBtn;
```

Viewvontroller.m

```
#import "sViewController.h"
#import "TableView.h"

@interface sViewController () <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation sViewController
{

    NSMutableArray *cells_Array;
    NSArray *jsonObject;

    int selectedIndex;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    cells_Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    selectedIndex = -1;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //NSArray *jsonObject;

    jsonObject = @[
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"199",
                       @"pointer": @"144"

                       },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"80",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"11"                   },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"30",
                       @"gamer": @"112",
                       @"pointer": @"14"


                       },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"100",
                       @"pointer": @"199"
                       },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"50",
                       @"gamer": @"19",
                       @"pointer": @"44"

                       },
                   @{
                       @"partner": @"2000",
                       @"gamer": @"500",
                       @"pointer": @"1000"
                       }
                   ];

    NSError *err;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];



    NSString * jsonString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    [cells_Array removeAllObjects];

    return [jsonObject count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView";
    TableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.lab1.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"gamer"];
    cell.lab2.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"partner"];
    cell.lab3.text = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row][@"pointer"];

    if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
    {
        [cell.checkBtn setSelected:true];
    }

    [cells_Array addObject:cell];

    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    for (TableView *view in cells_Array ) {
        [view.checkBtn setSelected:false];
    }
    TableView *cellView = [self.containerTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;

    [cellView.checkBtn setSelected:true];
}
@end
```

When i run my app. no date are showing in my table view.But my json date are showing in my `console`.I checked that.Please help me/what i missed.I am new to ios.Any thing i missed!

For your reference here is my [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxn6ippkp6ign8h/chumaa%20tableview.zip?dl=0)

But one of my already project that get help from SO its working .Here is that [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j02yotvevxfp821/jsonTableView%203.zip?dl=0)

But my projects is not working

Comment: Where is numberOfSectionsInTableView method, you should add this to show your data and return 1 if there is only one section.

Comment: what about your delegate and dataSource  setting in viewDidLoad and what about outlet of your table

Comment: that method is there...`numberof rows in section`

Comment: See my updated post..

Comment: @Spynet  din't get you??

Comment: HI first where is your table view outlet
eg. myTableView.delegate = self;
      myTableView.datasource = self;
where is that ?
that need to come inside View didload
Did you change the nib identifier  as @"TableView" or not ?

Comment: @Spynet  i did that `myTableView.delegate = self; myTableView.datasource = self; ` and also my nib identifier is called `tableview` that i already called.

Comment: @Spynet  but still not able to get

Comment: Your mistake was identifier naming one place in small case and other place in Camel Case. 


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView";

my nib identifier is called tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Tableview.xib file have two cell design part.to delete empty design and to set another design Identifier is "TableView".

Answer (score 0):

Checklist for `UIViewController` with manually added `UITableView`:

1. Make sure the `UITableView` is properly initialized and added as a subview to your view controller's main view (storyboard/xib or programmatically).
2. Make sure the table view's `dataSource` property is set to reference your view controller.
3. Make sure you implement the `UITableViewDataSource` method:

   `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

   ...and that it returns a value greater than zero.
4. Make sure you implement the UITableViewDataSource method:

   `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

   ...and that you return an instance of `UITableViewCell` (or any subclass thereof) fully configured to display your model data.

Comment: yes i did all in your solution but still not able to see my data

Comment: Check your data isn't empty, using breakpoints and/or `print()`.